# Universal Soldier franchise: order of watching the sequels

Tags: suggested-order, universal-soldier

I recently saw [*Universal Soldier* (1992)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105698/reference) and got interested in the other parts of the franchise. As far as I can see the franchise contains the following movies:

- [*Universal Soldier II: Brothers in Arms* (1998)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186654/reference)
- [*Universal Soldier III: Unfinished Business* (1999)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186655/reference)
- [*Universal Soldier: The Return* (1999)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0176269/reference)
- [*Universal Soldier: Regeneration* (2009)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1288403/reference)
- [*Universal Soldier: Day of Reckoning* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1659343/reference)

However, *Brothers in Arms* and *Unfinished Business* are DTV (Direct To Video) movies and *The Return*, *Regeneration* and *Day of Reckoning* are theatrical films. Right now I have only the theatrical ones in possession so in short I want to know if I can watch those movies without the DTV ones or should I wait untill I can get my hands on the other two?

Since I haven't seen any of the sequels and don't want to receive spoilers, I would appreciate it if answers could place any possible deeper story discussion into spoiler blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: This answer is spoiler free. The links have been included for reference, but opening them likely will lead to spoilers.*

[From the Universal Soldier wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier_(franchise)):

> After Universal Soldier was released, Carolco, the production company
> that backed the film, went bankrupt. In 1995, Carolco sold the rights
> of the series to Skyvision Entertainment in Toronto.
>
> Two TV films,
> ***Universal Soldier II: Brothers in Arms and Universal Soldier III:
> Unfinished Business***, were released direct-to-video...They were produced for Showtime / The Movie Channel as a
> miniseries meant as a backdoor pilot for a series. Having almost no
> input whatsoever from the original filmmakers, ***their canonical status
> is questionable***.
>
> ...***Universal
> Soldier: The Return...has since been removed from the series
> canon***. An overwhelming critical and financial failure, The Return
> contradicted several elements of the previous film's plot...
>
> The subsequent
> film in the series, ***Universal Soldier: Regeneration, disregards the
> events of The Return entirely***.

If I go to the *[Universal Soldier: The Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier:_The_Return)* page, it says:

> Subsequent films in the series ignore the events of The Return and
> contradict it in some places throughout the series; today it is no
> longer considered part of the series' canon.

Similarly, if I go directly to the *[Universal Soldier: Regeneration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier:_Regeneration)* wiki page, it says:

> The film is direct sequel to the original Universal Soldier from 1992,
> unrelated to the two Universal Soldier television sequels that were
> produced in 1998 and completely ignores the events from the 1999
> theatrical sequel Universal Soldier: The Return.

Finally, the *[Universal Soldier: Day of Reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Soldier:_Day_of_Reckoning)* page says:

> It is a semi-sequel to Universal Soldier: Regeneration.

So putting all of that together, it appears that the first film was released. Then two more direct to TV films were released. Then a fourth theatrical film was released, and has been *removed* from canon. A fifth film was then released, which served as a sequel to the first film, and a sixth film was released that serves as a semi-sequel to the fiffth film.

So, without the direct-to-tv films, I'd suggest this order:

1. Universal Soldier
2. Universal Soldier: Regeneration
3. Universal Soldier: Day of Reckoning

You can then watch the two direct to TV films, and Universal Soldier: The Return, if desired.

Comment: Detailed and yet without spoilers, I like! It's a weird franchise though. Half of the movies are ignored in one way or the other

Comment: @TimothyPersoon: Yes. I've never seen the series, but it seems quite strange!